# I don't have any snapshot listeners in my code. Why does listeners keep adding to the console?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I do not have a single call creating a listener in my code. I have searched my entire project and know that they do not exist. Also, all that I use are getDocument() calls, whether this be from the cache of server.

Comment: As I said before, it could be your usage of the Firebase console to examine data.  Stack Overflow can't determine the source of your reads, especially since we can't see your code, or know anything about what you're doing with your project.  If you think this chart is in error, contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm interested to know what you've discovered and what you tried to find the cause of reads in excess of those documented in the Firebase documentation.

Comment: Yes I contacted the Firebase team and the problem was that if you enter the data section at all it adds a ton of reads. So all I did was bookmarked the usage section and my read problem was fixed.